# GRASS executable in Shell with R

Tags: r, grass-7.0

I was trying to write a shell script using GRASS commands and I realized that I wanted to use R commands in my code but I couldn't find a way to execute the Rscript using my results from the GRASS commands, without using import/export commands. Is there a way to pass the results of my GRASS commands to my Rscript or execute R commands in the same script without using import/export commands? Meaning that I want to take an ndvi raster that I have calculated from GRASS GIS commands and print out some statistics using R commands.

P.S I hope I was clear enough and helped you understand my problem.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:scripting] tag because we are in the process of burninating it.  Using R indicates that you are scripting.  https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4648/do-we-need-scripting-and-automation-tags?cb=1

Comment: This is a bit unclear. You want to run a shell and run R from that shell prompt and then run GRASS from that R prompt? What's an "executable shell", because I don't think there's such a thing as a "non-executable shell".

Comment: @Spacedman No-no. I wanted to write a shellscript that both executes R and GRASS commands and after a long way of wrong answers I found a way to do so and I wanted to share it with the gis stackexchange community because I have passed through a lot of posts that want to either start GRASS GIS from R or they want to do a statistical analysis and they don't know where to start. I am not acting on behalf of them, I am just sharing my knowledge.

Answer (score -3):

There are libraries in R, really similar to the ones that PYTHON has, that can run GRASS code. Now if you are new and you want to start a shell script `!/bin/sh` you should install first the **rgrass7** library in R and you will need an older version of R to pull rasters from GRASS, given that you are having the usual;

> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘Χ’ is not available (for R version x.y.z)

and from there you can add parallel programing, maps or whatever else you want.

Comment: Could you include a sample script or R code or something here to make it clear what you've actually answered?